# Which Cloudera version supports YARN node labels

Tags: cloudera

I would like to know whether Cloudera supports YARN Node labels? if yes, then which version of Cloudera can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Found the information in one of the cloudera documentation:

[YARN Unsupported Features in Cloudera 6.2](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_cdh_620_unsupported_features.html#cdh620_unsupported_feat)

Node labels are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

CDH 6.3 still not supported.
https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_cdh_630_unsupported_features.html#yarn_600_unsupported

In CDP, Supported.
https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.0/yarn-allocate-resources/topics/yarn-configuring-node-labels.html